# GotFocus event not firing

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have an image inside a datatemplate on which I want to call a method when it gets focus, but the gotfocus event is not firing. Here is the code:

```
 <DataTemplate>
       <Canvas x:Name="cv">
              <Image x:Name="img1" Source = "{Binding ModelImage}" Stretch="Fill" Width="432" Height="357" MaxWidth="432" MaxHeight="357"/>
              <Image Source = "{Binding HairStyleImage}" Stretch="Fill" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="ResourceImage_ManipulationDelta"  GotFocus="focussed" LostFocus="lostFocus">
                      <Image.RenderTransform>
                             <CompositeTransform />
                      </Image.RenderTransform>
               </Image>
        </Canvas>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx)

> Image is not a true control in that it is not a descendant class of
> Control. You can't call focus to an Image or put it in a tab sequence.

So you can't call `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event for `Image` control.